# Check if another vertex has the same attribute value

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have a graph made with the Boost's graph library.  It is based on the adjaceny list structure.  I have the following simple definition of a vertex.

```
struct Vertex
{
    string unique_id_name;
};
```

I want to be able to test if a vertex with a given `unique_id_name` exists.  How can you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if()` - for example, suppose you are looking for `vertex_im_looking_for`.

If you are using C++11, you can plug in a lambda into `std::find_if()` - if not, you can plug in a standard functor (a predicate).

```
typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
tie(vi, vi_end) = vertices(my_graph);

bool found = std::find_if(
  vi, vi_end,                                               
  [&](const Vertex& vertex){ 
    return vertex.unique_id_name==vertex_im_looking_for.unique_id_name;
  }
)!=vi_end;
```

`std::find_if()` returns an iterator so you can compare with `vi_end` to see if you found what you are looking for.  If it equals `vi_end`, your vertex was not found.